# Hide a button inside a modal pop up using jquery?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, sharepoint-2013, rest, sharepoint-designer

Inside a modal pop up I have a button with id **createnewaccounts** how can I hide this?

This is modal code

```js
function OpenDialog(URL){
        var options = {

            url:URL,

            title:"",

            dialogReturnValueCallback: DialogCallback

            };
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
      }
```

```html
<a style="color:red" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OpenDialog('https://example.com/page.aspx')">click here</a>
```

is there a way I can hide an element with an id inside this pop-up?

Comment: can you share full source code as snippet ?

Comment: That is the whole code, modal pop up function and an anchor tag that calls the function on Onclick